# SPF record is showing up unchanged after several days

Tags: spf, gmail

I need to change my SPF record, but the one that Kitterman shows as being the present SPF record is not visible on my DNS server.

OLD ONE: `v=spf1 a mx include:e2ma.net ~all`

I added the new one and it is not showing up.  The old one will not change.

NEW ONE: `v=spf1 a mx include:e2ma.net include:_spf.google.com include:aspmx.pardot.com ~all`

Ugggg!  Hope this makes sense, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What domain is this for?

Comment: www.toafinish.com

Comment: thx for the advice.  i'll follow up with my host and get .

Comment: This is what I received from my host: Unfortunately, we cannot assist you because we are offering unmanaged Cloud VPS service at the moment. That means that you must setup and administrate your Cloud VPS server by yourself.  So back to the drawaing board.

Comment: Sounds like you should just hire someone for an hour to help you sort this out.

Comment: I think your right!

Answer (score 7):

Let's follow the trail of evidence here:

```
$ whois toafinish.com | grep "Name Server"
   Name Server: DNS1.HOST1PLUS.COM
   Name Server: DNS2.HOST1PLUS.COM
```

Those are the authoritative nameservers for your domain. Let's look at the current SPF records:

```
$ dig txt toafinish.com +short
"v=spf1 a mx include:e2ma.net ~all"
"spf2.0/pra a mx include:e2ma.net ~all"
```

OK, those are the current SPF records that are being returned by the authoritative servers for your domain.

So where is the disconnect? Well there are a couple options.

1. You are updating your DNS records in the wrong spot. Are you sure you're updating your records in Host1Plus's system?
2. You are indeed updating your records in Host1Plus's system, but for some reason they are not getting saved or not getting deployed correctly to their nameservers.

You really have one thing to check: are you updating your DNS records in the right location? If so, then you need to talk with your provider to see why things aren't getting updated as expected.

Comment: I would suggest always looking up the nameservers in DNS rather than relying on whois data for this. Especially when troubleshooting unexpected results it's better to look at the data that is actually used rather than informational text from another service. Eg `dig +trace +add toafinish.com NS` also makes it clear that mistakes have been made; the delegatory and authoritative sets of `NS` records do not match. In this particular case, one is a subset of the other, so that doesn't explain the problem in the question but it does highlight the value of actually looking at the real data.